# Updating a React component with new data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In a legacy web app, a React component was introduced, let's call it `CustomComponent`.

```
updateView(newData) {
  React.render(<CustomComponent data={newData} />, document.querySelector('.custom-component-1'));
}
```

This works, however for some reason the actual DOM node `.custom-component-1` seems to be *emptied* every time `React.render` is called on it, defeating the purpose of using React to achieve minimal DOM updates because each time it replaces the contents.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: My answer is incorrect, according to the api it should rerender if you render into an existing container.
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.render

Comment: Yes however actually React seems to be doing what you wrote in your answer, strange.

Answer (score -1):

When you use React.render, React doesn't test the existing virtual DOM against the previous virtual DOM -- it simply re-renders the component.

What you're referring to -- render only when state changes -- occurs on a `render` method within a component.

Example:

```
// always renders
React.render(<CustomComponent />, document.querySelector('.custom-component'));

// renders only when state changes
var CustomComponent = React.createClass({
  render() {
    I re-render only if my state changes
  }
});
```

Comment: Doesn't this contradict the documentation, though? https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.render As far as I know `React.render` will call the component's `render()`, even if props didn't change, but then not update the real DOM as the new virtual DOM will be exactly like the old one.